# How To Configure a noip on linux, if I has Double NAT ISP Like JioFi?

Tags: ubuntu, nat

I has a **JioFi** Wifi Router which is Double NAT ISP. So, I have a **WAN ip**

[image: WAN ip On Router Page]

and **external public ip**.

[image: public ip]

Whenever I do port forwarding the specific port, only it affects **WAN ip**.So As a Result I can't access my web server...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISP does NAT between its public IP (157.50.xx.xx) and the ISP internal private IP (10.89.xx.xx). Unless you can convince your ISP (by switching to the appropriate plan, usually for business, that gives you a personal public IP and paying more money, or whatever) to port forward the ports you need, there's nothing you can do.

The router you are using (JioFi, or whatever) hasn't got anything to do with this at all.

Other options are renting a server with a public IP somewhere. Or using IPv6, if your ISP doesn't NAT this (some do).

Comment: you are saying a rent a server from cloud provider like yellowcircle, alibaba cloud...